# Not able to Connect Netlify in GitHub

Tags: javascript, github, debugging, deployment, netlify

I am not able to connect my GitHub Organisation to Netlify whenever I am trying to connect its showing

> `This page is taking too long to load.`
> `Sorry about that. Please try refreshing and contact us if the problem persists.`

It's happening only with me, my friends can connect easily. Can anyone please help me with this? [Error by GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV1r4.png)

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. And what's exceptionally strange is that I already have 3 repos connected using this Netlify account, all with the same github account. Now all of a sudden, it's giving me this error message when I try to configure a new repo to connect with Netlify. Frustrating.